# Does there always exist an optimal solution to the metric steiner tree problem which doesn't contain any steiner nodes?

Tags: optimization, trees, computational-geometry

Given an undirected graph with nonnegative edge weights and a partition of the vertex
set into terminals and Steiner vertices, the Steniner tree problem consists in finding a
minimum weight tree in the graph that contains all terminals and any subset of the
Steiner vertices.

The metric steiner tree problem is when the edges satisfy the triangle inequality. Would this not imply that for every instance of the problem, there exists an optimal solution containing no Steiner vertices (since you can shortcut the path containing the Steiner vertex down to a path with just terminals, without increasing the weight)?

Comment: "since you can shortcut the path": how so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The problem is that a single Steiner vertex can be involved in multiple of these shortcut operations. In the first shortcut operation, the total weight of the edges decreases (at the cost of disconnecting the tree), but not necessarily in later shortcut operations, as then you are shortcutting a path of which some edges may already have been removed.

Concretely, there are instances where not using Steiner vertices is suboptimal. For example: let the terminals be the three vertices of an equilateral triangle with side-length $1$ and a Steiner vertex at the center of the triangle. All vertices have an edge, with the weight equal to their Euclidean distance. If we do not use the Steiner vertex, then the tree consists of two sides of the triangle, and its weight is $2$. However, the star centered at the Steiner vertex in the middle of triangle has weight $\sqrt{3} < 2$ (as the distance from a vertex of a triangle to its center is $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3}$)

Answer (score 2):

Steiner nodes give more freedom to make shortcuts so they cannot lead to worse solutions. And it is easy to find examples where they give better solutions.

In fact, Steiner points have been introduced just for that purpose.

Comment: I couldn't think of an example where it could give a better solution in the metric case (the other answer provided one).

Comment: @SVMteamsTool: what did you try ? Works with a scalene triangle, works with a square or rectangle, works with a regular pentagon. And you find loads of examples on the Web.

Comment: I was thinking of it in general terms - If my terminals were {a,b} and I had just 1 steiner vertex c, with (a,c) and (b,c) having some weights x and y, if we have a Steiner tree consisting of those two edges, we could always shortcut it to (a,b), however I didn't take into account the fact that the same Steiner vertex could essentially be used in multiple shortcuttings hence the overall cost of using a Steiner vertex could be lower

Comment: @SVMteamsTool: Steiner vertices are usually of degree $3$ (at least).